# VBA - Match header and copy data to another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am creating a macro that copies all data below the header to another worksheet.

I have a code like this:

```
Sub CopyData()

  Dim a As Range

  'Find "1" in Row 2
  With Sheets(1).Rows(2)
   Set a = .Find("1", lookat:=xlPart)
   'If found, copy the column to range A1 of sheet2
   If Not a Is Nothing Then
    Columns(a.Column).EntireColumn.Copy _
      Destination:=Sheets(2).Range("A1")
   End If
 End With
End Sub
```

I have a problem here:

```
Columns(a.Column).EntireColumn.Copy _
Destination:=Sheets(2).Range("A1")
```

`EntireColumn.Copy` will include copying the header. I only want to copy all data below the header.

Any alternative to replace `EntireColumn.Copy`?

Answer (score 0):

I'd go like follows:

```
Sub CopyData()
    Dim a As Range

    With Sheets(1)
        Set a = .Rows(2).Find("1", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlPart) '<--| try finding "1" in Row 2
        'If found, copy the column to range A1 of sheet2
        If Not a Is Nothing Then .Range(a.Offset(1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, a.Column).End(xlUp)).Copy Destination:=Sheets(2).Range("A1")
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @WeiHau, did you get through it?